# Can someone identify this biplane from 1920-21 taken in Arkansas?

Tags: aviation-history, aircraft-identification, biplane

[image]Can someone identify this biplane? It was taken in late 1920 or early 1921 when my grandfather was barnstorming in Arkansas. My grandmother and aunts are also in the photos. Additionally, can someone identify where in Arkansas this Hickman Air_____ was located?

Comment: I have no way to confirm if it was the same place, but there is a private airfield called “Hickman Airport” near Black Oak, AR.  I looked around on google maps and couldn’t actually fins anything resembling a usable grass runway any more.  The AirNav page identifies at as being at `35.8311056,-90.3704139`.  See also:  http://www.airnav.com/airport/2AR8

Comment: Thanks for the info

Comment: "Hickman Air..." looks like it's followed by a "B", not an "F" or "P". However, I can find no record of a "Hickman Airbase", the closest an internet search comes up with is "Hickam Air Base" in Oahu. I _smidge_ too far away to be a likely candidate...

Comment: Thanks for the response

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like a [Curtiss Oriole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curtiss_Oriole). Note the smooth and rounded fuselage and how it comes to a rounded point under the tail. Additionally, note the engine manifold covers and some sort of extended "stack" from the rear of the engine.

[image]

[image]

*Image source: [Northwest Airlines History Center](https://northwestairlineshistory.org/aircraft-curtiss-oriole/)*

Comment: somehow these tail surfaces plan form are futuristic